# HowTo launch node --debug grunt server on Windows?

Tags: windows, node.js, gruntjs, node-inspector

Running Windows 8.1 and my environment is working great except I cannot start node in --debug so that node-inspector has something to connect to.

I have a Gruntfile setup with grunt-concurrent that lets me open, grunt-devtools, node-inspector then watch just fine but I can't figure out a workable syntax for getting that running with node in debug. Following is what I'd expect to work but also the error I get when I try. Notice that there is a message indicating that the debug server is listening, but something falls apart from there and fails so it does me no good.

```
C:\PROJECTS\bManWebService_Hapi>node --debug C:\Users\rainabba\AppData\Roaming\npm\grunt server

debugger listening on port 5858

C:\Users\rainabba\AppData\Roaming\npm\grunt:2
basedir=`dirname "$0"`
        ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    at Module._compile (module.js:437:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
    at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the file C:\Users\rainabba\AppData\Roaming\npm\grunt is not a JS file but a bash shell script. Look for grunt.cmd in the same folder if you need Windows-compatible version.

And event if you find grunt.cmd - starting it as `node grunt.cmd` is not a proper way. Most likely the `grunt.cmd` will start the node so you need to somehow pass the --debug argument to the node, called by the grunt.cmd or just run node exactly as grunt.cmd runs it.

Comment: THanks. grunt.cmd is starting node and then calling a binary grunt. That led to me to see that I could either edit grunt.cmd or use grunt-node-inspector or grunt-nodemon to get a debugger running (they launch their own instance of node). Now if I can just figure out why the node-inspector page won't connect to the debugger.....

Answer (score 1):

### tl; tr;

**node --debug-brk c:\Users\rainabba\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\grunt-cli\bin\grunt taskname**

You have to use this executable

- **c:\Users\rainabba\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\grunt-cli\bin\grunt**

instead of this

- c:\Users\rainabba\AppData\Roaming\npm\grunt server

Comment: This worked for me when I was trying to start a grunt task from inside WebStorm, running it as a debug configuration instead of from the grunt console. (Running on Windows 7 Enterprise.)